# "Test Agent could not connect to the test controller" VS2012 Agents

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

(Using the Visual Studio 2012 Agents tools for testing)

I'm having difficulty getting my test agent (on a remote machine) to connect with my test controller.

I'm getting the error message:

> "Test agent could not connect to the test controller"

In the log, the following errors are present:

Some of the errors are shown multiple times, so I have indicate the number of times beside them.

x2:

> "Could not get the status from the test agent. Exception: Failed to
>   connect to an IPC Port: The system cannot find the file specified."

x1:

> "Could not get the status from the test agent. Exception: Requested
>   Service not found"

x1:

> "Could not get the status from the test agent. Exception: Failed to
>   write an IPC Port: The pipe is being closed"

x3 :

> "Could not get the status from the test agent. Exception: Failed to
>   connect to an IPC Port: The system cannot find the file specified."

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the issue.

Despite my Test Agent reporting success with creating the Firewall exceptions, I examined my Inbound Rules for my Firewall and discovered that the two exceptions for the QTAgentService.exe were actually blocked.

I had previously installed the Visual Studio 2010 agent tool on this machine. These exceptions were still enabled.

I'm unsure why they were blocked, but one possibility is that my anti-virus software blocked it (AVG anti-virus I have installed). I didn't have the same problem with the VS2010 agent tool.

Once I un-blocked both exceptions (one is UDP, the other is TCP), my test agent successfully connected with my test controller.

Comment: I was also getting the error: "Could not get the status from the test agent. Exception: Failed to connect to an IPC Port: The system cannot find the file specified." Wasn't a firewall problem for me - using {domain}\{username} instead of {username]@{domain} fixed it for me... Figured I'd leave a note here in case it helps someone troubleshooting the error in the title

Comment: Commenting out all references to 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You should disable both UAC and Firewall. I faced with this issue and solution was to disable UAC in registry. It is applicable for Window 8+ hosts, if you are running Test Controller or Test Agent on it.
Refer to this article: [link](http://www.eightforums.com/system-security/2434-disable-uac-completely.html)
You can do it by the following command:
`reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`