# "Test agent could not connect to the test controller" VS2013 Agents

Tags: visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I am receiving the error when trying to register a test agent to the load test controller

```
Configuration started on 2015/10/16, 16:05:47.
OS Version : Microsoft Windows NT 6.3.9600.0
Executable version : 12.0.21005.1

I, 2015/10/16, 16:06:07.812, Restarted service successfully.
I, 2015/10/16, 16:06:07.968, Verifying that the test agent is able to connect to the test controller.
E, 2015/10/16, 16:08:10.005, Test agent could not connect to the test controller.
I, 2015/10/16, 16:08:10.005, Disabling auto logon on the machine...
I, 2015/10/16, 16:08:10.005, Adding agent setting AutoLogonEnabledByAgentConfiguration=0 on agent machine
```

In the windows event log, this is seen:

```
Unable to connect to the controller on 'machinename:6901'. The server has rejected the client credentials.
The logon attempt failed
```

I've tried all I can find for people that have reported similar issues (Firewall is disabled, no antivirus, UAC is disabled, user is in admin group as well as TeamTestAgentService/ControllerAdmins/ControllerUsers).  I've tried running the setup under different users/same user/"as admin" while still using the same username/pass for the log on.  Trying to point different machines Test Agents to this  controller and the same error occurs.  Per another site, I also tried adding this to QTAgentService.exe.config

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="BindTo" value="x.x.x.x"/>
  </appSettings>
```

I have also tried using a different account for the Controller vs Test Agent.  IE Both CtrlUser and TestUser are in the same groups listed above.  As I understand it thought, this should work since they should be the same name/pass for Workgroup authentication.

I've referenced these pages among others and unless I've missed something, those solutions do not apply.

- ["Test Agent could not connect to the test controller" VS2012 Agents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249093/test-agent-could-not-connect-to-the-test-controller-vs2012-agents)
- [VS2013 Test agent and controller not communicating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104469/vs2013-test-agent-and-controller-not-communicating)
- [VS2013 Remote load test agent can't connect to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981451/vs2013-remote-load-test-agent-cant-connect-to-controller)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59bc2270-37d9-4297-ac3f-e0da21d10a95/test-agent-could-not-connect-to-the-test-controller-vs2012-agents

Any thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a version downloaded by a prior employee that we have been using for CodedUI testing (12.0.21005.1).  I downloaded the latest version (2013 Update 5) and after installing that, it worked with the same settings I was using before.